# Обособление и синтаксическая роль слова "вообще"

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова, наречия

Предложение такое: ***Ты работать будешь вообще или нет?***

Нужно обособлять? Почему-то не хочется... Пользователи тоже не знают, результат фифти-фифти.

А вы как думаете? Чем здесь является слово "вообще"?

Comment: Если поставить запятые, будет вводное слово (= "вообще говоря"). Без запятых -- это наречие, используемое как подытоживающее (см. пятое значение в фэдвебе: http://feb-web.ru/feb/mas/mas-abc/03/ma121007.htm?cmd=0&istext=1).

Comment: Мне кажется, что здесь нет этих значений: ни вообще говоря, ни итога. Есть ирония и раздражение/возмущение.  Как мне это выразить?  (Да и в принципе  названные вами варианты по семантике похожи, различить их сложно.)

Comment: А какой ещё из словарных вариантов можно счесть подходящим в вашем случае и в ряде подобных (типа "Ну ты вообще зажрался" и т. п.)? Только "подытоживающее" и подходит, как по мне. Имеется-то в виду именно какой-никакой, а итог: например "То ты не выспался, то тебе холодно, то материал не тот... Ты работать вообще будешь?"

Comment: "Ну,  ты вообще зажрался" – здесь эмоции выражены и ударения расставлены. Вообще – междометное наречие, вот как я его назову. А теперь подберите, пжста, знаки для темы про работу. Тоже с эмоциями!

Comment: Неа. Я сказал, как сумел, и именно потому комментарием, а не ответом, что не хочу углубляться в тему, искать прецеденты и проч. Не хочу углубляться, хочу углупляться. Смотреть в глупь себя!

Comment: А это как? Может, мне тоже попробовать. Это такая релаксация, да?

Comment: Она самая)) Смиряет и ободряет))

Comment: А как научиться?   Только мне бы хотелось легкости и безмятежности, это тоже можно?

Comment: Как известно, царь Соломон носил перстень с надписью "И это пройдёт". Вот рецепт лёгкости и безмятежности) Вот вам для настроения: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-cO7I2L7N0

Comment: Я бы вот так поставил, но может это неверно: Ты работать будешь вообще, или нет?

Answer (score 1):

Не нужно обособлять? По-всякому бывает...

Это такое **необыкновенное слово**, что ему тесны любые рамки, в том числе Справочная служба. Я бы назвала его **МЕЖДОМЕТНЫМ НАРЕЧИЕМ,**  но в словаре нет такого значения. В этом слове вся русская душа с вечными поисками и сомнениями,  пониманием и непониманием.

В нем столько эмоций, что стихами не выразишь.

Вот такое это слово.

Прочитаем еще раз комментарии и убедимся в этом.

```
 Мне кажется, что здесь нет этих значений: ни вообще говоря, 
 ни итога. Есть ирония и раздражение/возмущение. Как мне это 
 выразить? (Да и в принципе названные вами варианты по 
 семантике похожи, различить их сложно.)  

 А какой ещё из словарных вариантов можно счесть подходящим 
 в вашем случае и в ряде подобных (типа "Ну ты вообще 
 зажрался" и т. п.)? Только "подытоживающее" и подходит, как 
 по мне. Имеется-то в виду именно какой-никакой, а итог: 
 например "То ты не выспался, то тебе холодно, то материал 
 не тот... Ты работать вообще будешь?" – 

"Ну, ты вообще зажрался" – здесь эмоции выражены и ударения 
 расставлены. Вообще – междометное наречие, вот как я его 
 назову. А теперь подберите, пжста, знаки для темы про 
 работу. Тоже с эмоциями! – 

 Неа. Я сказал, как сумел, и именно потому комментарием, а 
 не ответом, что не хочу углубляться в тему, искать 
 прецеденты и проч. Не хочу углубляться, хочу углупляться. 
 Смотреть в глупь себя!  

 А это как? Может, мне тоже попробовать. Это такая 
 релаксация, да? 

 Она самая)) Смиряет и ободряет)) 

 А как научиться? Только мне бы хотелось легкости и 
 безмятежности, это тоже можно?

 Как известно, царь Соломон носил перстень с надписью "И это 
пройдёт". Вот рецепт лёгкости и безмятежности) Вот вам для 
настроения: youtube.com/watch?v=H-cO7I2L7N0
```

**Да, надо глядеть на звезды...**

*"Бывает, на звёзды глядишь из окна своей кухни
И видишь такую гармонию, жизнь такую!
Одна там сверхновая вспыхнет, другая потухнет..."* Тимур Шатов.

*Я, **вообще**, гляжу иногда на звезды.*.. (вводное слово).

*Я **вообще** гляжу иногда на звезды, но надо бы чаще* (наречие).

Категорический императив Канта https://dzen.ru/a/Xc12IqKKLxgPK2eU

Answer (score 0):

Запятые ставить не нужно:

*Ты работать будешь **вообще** или нет?*

*Вообще* — наречие.

На похожий вопрос вы уже отвечали, и там было то же значение *вообще*, что и здесь:

[image: Кто-нибудь мне ответит вообще?]

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение. Это очень интересная тема, а решения  бывают разные.